# PHP - Created a navigation from directory files but page 1 displays twice

Tags: php, navigation, pagination, directory

So I have my navigation based on directory files here, however it outputs the first page twice.

I currently have 6 files in my directory: index.php, 2.php, 3.php, 4.php, 5.php and 6.php

My navigation displays the page links as [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [1]

How do i prevent the index.php [1] from printing again at the end?

```
<?php
$pathfiles = "../directory/";
$files = glob("../directory/*.php");
$key = array_search('index.php', $files);
unset($files[$key]);
natsort($files);
array_unshift($files, 'index.php');
foreach( $files as $file ) {
    echo '[<a href="'.($pathfiles).''
    .basename($file).'">'.str_replace('index', '1', basename($file,".php")).'</a>] ';
}
?>
```

Any solutions or leads would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the array_unshift to this:

```
array_unshift($files, array_pop($files));
```

This will basically move the last entry to the first position, see the PHP documentation for [array_pop](http://php.net/array_pop).

Answer (score 0):

I'am affraid that `array_search()` can't find the result . Check `var_dump($files)` and `var_dump($key)`.